# X-Forwarded-For (XFF) showing multiple values behind ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-elb

I have a httpd process running on EC2 instance behind ELB. I am not running any proxy. My connection flow is

Client PC -> ELB -> HTTPD.

I am getting two IPs in my httpd log, one of the client and another of ELB.

```
54.248.250.235, 172.31.38.132 - - [21/Feb/2015:10:57:00 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Data/1.0 (1093763)
```

My LogFormat configuration is as follows

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /log/httpd/accesslog_%m%d%Y_%H.log" combined
```

I want to only log Client IP and not ELB IP.